# Is there a way to see which question/answer awarded the badge?

Tags: support

Is there a way to see which question/answer awarded the badge ?

eg: **Favorite Question** : Which question helped to earn that badge? Like that is there a way to see which question/answer awarded the badge ?

Comment: Did you read the definition of the Unsung Hero badge? It is not awarded for any **single** answer. It is about percentages and totals. If you have more that 10 zero scored answers and these are at least 25% of your answers, you get the badge.

Comment: For easy understanding, I simply put a badge name. Let me update my question

Answer (score 2):

If the badge is awarded for a specific post, you can see it.
For example, you can see which questions were awarded the "Favorite question" on Meta Stack Overflow:

https://meta.stackoverflow.com/help/badges/33/favorite-question

You can see this page by clicking the "Badges" link and clicking the badge you're interested in.

For your own badges, if they're awarded for a specific post, go to your profile page and click on the badge.
Similarly, if you want to know why another user got a specific badge, go to that user's profile page and click on the badge.

Answer (score 1):

No there is not a way. Because Badge is not for a particular question or answer. Some time it is for activity or task

check below link for more details why and how we get badge

https://meta.stackoverflow.com/help/badges

**Favorite Question** badge is given for Question favorited by 25 users. This badge can be awarded multiple times. So u can check which question get the upvote of about 25 or more